# Get Content after the remote URL load successfully

Tags: javascript, php, curl, file-get-contents

I am using this function for getting contents from Remote URL

```
function get_contents($purl)
{
$ch = curl_init($purl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$page = $curl_scraped_page;
return $page;
}
```

It get content nicely but the one which uses Javascript to load. 
It remains same like

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

I want the inside content also.

> I want a function which get content after loading of all js.

Comment: Use PhantomJS, not cURL.

Comment: Can you show us what content do you get and how get_contents is used in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content in in html element is filled by ajax, you will need to intercept the ajax response or you will need to identify the javascript method that populates the content in html.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with plane cURL/PHP out of the box. Because cURL will read the plane source code only.

You can use a tool like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).